# SOLR query to find the exact match of the passed String with comma separated or subset of it in the query

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I'd like TO query a string to Solr and let it answer with all records which are a subset of that string.

The string is separated by comma. I wanna make solr to give me all records where a specific string field is a subset of the string provide as the request .

An example.

Imagine I have an string field indexed in Solr which is a set of string separated by comma. For example, let's say I have the following record's field indexed in Solr:

"AAA, AAB"

"AAA"

"AAA, AAB, AAC"

"AAA, AAB, AAC, AAD"

"AAA,AAC,AAD"

"AAA,AAD"

"AAD"

"AAB,AAC"

I wanna Solr to receive a query with, for example, "AAA, AAD" and reply with the following records:

"AAA"

"AAA ,AAD"

"AAD"

If I query by "AAA, AAB, AAC" the retrieved records would be...

"AAA"

"AAA,AAB"

"AAA ,AAB, AAC"

"AAB ,AAC"

The retrieved records must be exactly a subset of the string provided

Is it possible to make Solr behave like this?

Comment: try using the filter fq ad pass the array of ids

Comment: I tried it as fq= id:"1,2,3" but solr will display the data with id 1,2,3,4 aswell  which is invalid

Comment: Could you please share the full query? Ans share the sample data?

Comment: <field name="Ids" type="commaDelimited" indexed="true" stored="true"/> my schema.xml entry

Comment: Ids:"calibration_overall,emp_profile"

Comment: How many ids could be present in your query? You'll probably have to keep the field as a sorted list of the numbers, then match on each possible version - i.e. `foo:"1" OR foo:"1,2" OR foo:"1,2,3"`.

Comment: The field will have to be of a `string` type in that case, since you only want exact matches.

Comment: it should give exact match along with the sub set of it , since string only support exact match, expected is if im passing id:(1,2,3) then output expected is id:(1,2,3) and its subset

Comment: @MatsLindh Can you please help me out on this ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm suggesting. If you want to query for `1,2,3`, query for `1,2,3`, `1,2` and `1`. That will give you all subsets, as long as the ids are sorted on both input and output.

Comment: So do i need to change the Schema entries ?